# Does Firebase Analytics persist User Properties

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

When you set a UserProperty with

`mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("favorite_food", mFavoriteFood);`

does it get saved for all the following Sessions until

`mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("favorite_food", null);`
is called? Or do I have to set this UserProperty on every app start?

Can automatically tracked events like `app_start` even have a UserProperty then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A call to `setUserProperty()` will be persistent for all future sessions. Once set, all future logged events will be tagged with that user property. You do not need to call it each time your app starts.

This [help article](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317519) has some additional info:

> Properties are effectively sticky event parameters that are automatically logged with every subsequent call to `logEvent`. After you set a user property value, it will be associated with every event logged afterwards...

Comment: Thanks! Would be nice if it the documentation would be more specific by saying all `logEvent` call in subsequent sessions and not only calls. Also having it in the API reference would help reduce the uncertainty.

Comment: Hi. The article linked no longer states that information. Are we sure they're still persisting? It doesn't appear to be the case for me in debug view.

Comment: I just found the information on the API docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#public-void-setuserproperty-string-name,-string-value

I guess there's issues with DebugView

Answer (score 0):

setUserProperty sets a user property to a given value. Once set, user property values persist throughout the app lifecycle and across sessions.